# React Native - Async Storage error when run react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to run react-native run-android but receive the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\Work\CS\Wms-Mobile\CS-WmsMobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java:26: error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
                                            ^
D:\Work\CS\Wms-Mobile\CS-WmsMobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java:34: error: cannot find symbol     
@ReactModule(name = AsyncStorageModule.NAME)
 ^
  symbol: class ReactModule
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\Work\CS\Wms-Mobile\CS-WmsMobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Things I've tried:

- Reinstall node_modules
- cd ./android and then ./gradlew clean

But none of them seems to work. I am glad to hear your suggestion, thank you in advance!

My version:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.4

android gradle plugin: 3.5.3

gradle: 5.4.1
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with below command

```
react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage
```

feel free for doubts

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, and also with react native version 0.60 +, React Native does the linking for us so when I try to link it manually, it will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solutions.

1. Uninstall Node Modules
2. Clean Gradle (`cd android && gradlew clean`)
3. now install back your modules (`yarn install`)

if this does not help try upgrading your packages.

`yarn upgrade --pattern react-native`

Answer (score 1):

Open the AVD Manager and try to start your phone emulator with Cold Boot, then close all applications. Clean and compile your application again, it must work now.
Sometimes even when you clean your application, your emulator get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations usually has something to do with Jetpack migrations 
Try using this [Jetifier tool](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier)

Just make sure to run `npx jetify` at the project root.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` solved the issue in my case. `sudo react-native ...`, `sudo ./gradlew ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your android/build.gradle file

```
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    // NOTE: if you are in a monorepo, you may have "$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```