# React native community async storage compiledebug javawithjavac Error when run app

Tags: compiler-errors, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to run React Native project. When I run app then this type of message always show. I clean my Android directory by using `./gradlew clean` but I was failed. Then I removed **node_modules & package.lock file**, then using `npm install` command.

Finally I can't solve my problem. Here I share my package and run time error image.

Here is my package link:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNu7D.png

Then runtime error link is:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyq3L.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Async Storage error when run react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510896/react-native-async-storage-error-when-run-react-native-run-android)