# Error when building app using react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building a react native app for android using the command react-native run-android, and I'm getting the following error while building the app:

```
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
35 actionable tasks: 35 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Async Storage error when run react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510896/react-native-async-storage-error-when-run-react-native-run-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is on react-native-async-storage node module, remove and reinstall async storage node module

1. `npm uninstall --save package_name`
2. `npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

if you're using react-native version<=0.59 do following step also

3. `react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`